# Testing using local files

Tags: testing, go, mocking

I'm looking for what best practice I should use when it comes to testing with Go using local files.

By using local files, I mean that in order to test functionality, the application needs some local files, as the application reads from these files frequently.

I'm not sure if I should write temporary files myself just before running the tests using the ioutil package tempdir and tempfile functions, or create a test folder like so;

```
testing/...test_files_here
main.go
main_test.go
```

and then read from the contents inside

```
testing/...
```

Comment: A folder named `testdata` is usually used for this purpose as it is ignored by the go tool (see `go help packages`)

Comment: Ah yes I see it. 

"Directory and file names that begin with "." or "_" are ignored
by the go tool, as are directories named "testdata"

Didn't spot that. Thank you

Comment: Admittedly, this is the lazy approach, but I put my testdata right next to the `*_test.go` files: Easy to access, easy to find and I do not mind to have them around. Another option would be to use `//go:generate` and [go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata) before creating a dist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is my current test setup:

```
app/
   main.go
   main_test.go
   main_testdata

   package1/
     package1.go 
     package1_test.go 
     package1_testdata1

   package2/
     package2.go 
     package2_test.go 
     package2_testdata1
```

All the test data that is specific to a single package, is placed within the directory of that package. Common test data that will be used by multiple packages are either placed in the application root or in `$HOME`.

This set up works for me. Its easy to change the data and test, without having to do extra typing:

`vim package1_test_data1; go test app/package1`

Answer (score 26):

A folder named `testdata` is usually used for this purpose as it is ignored by the go tool (see go help packages).

Comment: Official docs mention "testdata": https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go/internal/test